# How do I copy and paste cells without cell formula with Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to copy and paste a range of cells into another range in Excel. My current code is copying the formulas over to the new range. However, I only want the cell values to be copied and not the formula tied to the cell. How can I do that?

`$copy3 = $worksheet.range("AF9:AF705").copy()
$paste3 = $worksheet.range("P9:P705").pastespecial($copy3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Excel question not a PowerShell one. So, you need to look at the Excel object model to make sure you are using the right code.

[Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839476.aspx)

The fact the you are using PowerShell as part of this effort, is really moot.

Workbook Example:

```
$xl=new-object -com excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$xl.visible = $true
$xl.displayAlerts=$false

#$xlPasteValues = $wb1.Range('A1','A1')

$wb1=$xl.workbooks.open($SourceWorkbook, $null, $true)
$wb2=$xl.workbooks.open($TargetWorkbook)

$targetRange=$wb2.Worksheets.Item($TargetWorksheet).Range('B3','B3')

$wb1.Worksheets.Item($SourceWorksheet).Range('C5','C5').copy()
$wb2.Worksheets.Item($TargetWorksheet).Activate()

$targetRange.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

In addition, in this scenario, you could also can assign the value directly like:

```
targetRange.Value=SourceRange.Value
```

Comment: Very nice, especially the point about assigning the value directly! In case anyone is reading this and wondering where `-4163` came from, it corresponds to `xlPasteValues` in the [xlPasteType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) enum.

Comment: I have only been able to assign the value directly with `$targetRange.Value2 = $SourceRange.Value2`...

Comment: Yeppers, I meant to add the xlPasteValue part, because I took it out, because I showed / explained the use of the macro recorder to get the needed Excel VBA code, which shows the method, and the covert that to PowerShell, but decided that was a bit much and yanked it before posting.

Comment: Btw, good use of [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/effb3d1d-69ce-461d-b4f5-ed378a1beb96/need-help-performing-paste-special-inside-powershell?forum=exceldev) lol.

Comment: It was that or using this... http://kiran-reddy.in/projects/powershell-excel.. I collect and keep a ton of things is a OneNote library file that I discover, because it will sooner or later come back and hit you in the face. The adage is, with the internets, if you have a question like this, it's probably already been asked and answered is part or whole somewhere - though you may have to dig more than you'd like. You have to be willing to dig, to find it and save it for later use and or sharing.